# AutoCompleteTextView drop down not showing weirdly

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, textwatcher, unicode-normalization

Suggestions are stored in an `ArrayList<String>.` The `getSuggestions()` method returns the right list of `String`, the point is that I replace special chars with casual ones. I.E. when I type `xeres`, I'd like to have the same results as if I had typed `xérès`, which is what happens but the problem here is that when I type `xérès`, the `dropdown` appears, and when I type `xeres`, it doesn't, even if suggestions variable has the same values...

```
@Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     if (s.length() > 2) {
        suggestions = getSuggestions(s.toString());
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dropdown_textview_row, suggestions);
        autoTxtSearchPointer.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help ! :)

**EDIT : more precise code**

```
    autoTxtSearchPointer = new AutoCompleteTextViewCustom(this);
    autoTxtSearchPointer.setHint(R.string.search);
    autoTxtSearchPointer.setSingleLine();
    autoTxtSearchPointer.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    autoTxtSearchPointer.setLayoutParams(editParams);
    autoTxtSearchPointer.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
    autoTxtSearchPointer.setThreshold(2);
    autoTxtSearchPointer.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 2) {
                suggestions = getSuggestions(s.toString());
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dropdown_textview_row, suggestions);
                autoTxtSearchPointer.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

}

**EDIT 2 : Is it because I use a Normalizer?**

```
private String normalize(String str) {
        return Normalizer
            .normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD)
            .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use **`Edittest`** and **`onTextChanged`** for this purpose.

Use **below code:**

```
AutoCompleteTextView text;

text = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,your_array_list);
text.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In **XML**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"            
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Comment: Please reconsider your answer with the code I added, and I don't use xml for this object.